# Configuring Eclipse with g++ on WSL

Tags: eclipse, g++, eclipse-cdt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The normal way to run C, C++ program on windows is to install Cygwin or MinGW. But now with WSL2 for Windows we have g++ out of the box in Windows. How to link g++ with eclipse on Windows.
I am not sure if I am using eclipse CDT. But here is a screenshot from within Eclipse->Help->About Eclipse IDE
[image]